# Bind Ctrl-C in fish vi-mode to switch from insert mode to normal mode

Tags: fish

I would like to use Ctrl-C to go from insert to normal mode in fish vi-mode, as I do in vim. I'm fairly new to fish and couldn't get it to work, though I tried this in my config.fish:

bind -M insert \cc set fish_bind_mode 'default'

Strangely I am able to go from Visual to Normal mode with Ctrl-C.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Binding [ctrl-C] would require that you also change the `stty intr` character. Something that is currently impossible from within fish due to how it handles tty modes. You could, however, change it before starting fish. That would then free the character to be bound as you wish. Though you'll need to do this to get the correct behavior:

```
bind -M insert \cc 'set fish_bind_mode default; commandline -f repaint'
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I put that in my config.fish. I also tried binding to other key combinations such as ctrl-x with \cx. Still didn't work, just does nothing.

Comment: Did you first run `stty intr ^x` (or bind some other key to the keyboard interrupt function)? You have to do that from another shell like bash or zsh then start fish from that shell.

Also, the reason [ctrl-C] taks you from visual to normal mode is that you're pressing the interrupt key which causes fish to change mode as a consequence of handling the interrupt.

Comment: Also, you can't change key bindings in your `config.fish`. User key bindings have to go in a function named `fish_user_key_bindings`. That function would normally be put in a file named `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish`.

Comment: Thanks. I put the function into that file, which now reads:
 `fzf_key_bindings  

function fish_user_key_bindings  
bind -M insert \cx 'set fish_bind_mode default; commandline -f repaint'  
end`  
(I wanted to try with Ctrl-x.) I then call the function in fish shell. It still doesn't work though.